# how to show some user posts to ajax api vue js

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

i just display 5 users post in modal

html

```html
<div id="app">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="user,i in users">
          <td> <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1 v-on:click="Showpost(user.id, i)">{{user.id}}</b-button></td>
          <b-modal  id="modal-1" title="info" >
            <p class="my-4">{{posts.title}}</p>
          </b-modal>
          <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

js

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    users: [],
    posts: [],
  },
  methods: {
    Showpost(id,i) {
      console.log("id",id);
      console.log("i",i)
      fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=" + id)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.posts = data[i];
        })
    },
  },
  computed: {
    object: function(){
      return this.posts.filter(function(post){
        return post.userId >= 5
      })
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.users = data;
      })
  },
});
```

Comment: What is your problem or question? FYI, `v-for="user,i in users"` should be `v-for="(user, i) in users"`

Comment: @Phil im display all posts users in modal, this code display just 1 posts users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will do so simple code to clear how this should be done

at first

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(user,index) in users">
      <td> <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1 v-on:click="showUserPosts(user.id,index)">{{user.id}}</b-button></td>
      <b-modal  id="modal-1" title="info" >
      </b-modal>
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

then 
instead of

```
      this.posts = data[i];
```

do it

```
      this.posts = data;
```

and in your html
under the table tag
do

```
<p v-for="(post,index) in posts" v-text="post.title"></>
```

if you want just show one post not many
make

```
data:function {
return{
users: [],
posts: {},
}
 },
```

and

```
<p v-if="post.title" v-text="post.title"></>
```

I hope this help you.
Good luck!

Comment: this code is working tank you , please say me how display just 5 posts

Comment: You can add slice <p v-for="(post,index) in posts.slice(0,5)" v-text="post.title"></>
You can check 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp
slice: returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

Comment: You can do that this.posts.slice(0,5) after getting the response